# Creating struct in javascript

Tags: javascript

I used a post i found on stackoverflow to create my own "struct creator", but it seems to not work, i dont understand why ...

```
function makeStruct(names) {
    var names = names.split(' ');
    var count = names.length;
    function constructor() {
        for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
            this[names[i]] = arguments[i];
        }
        for (var i = 5; i < count; i++) {
            this[names[i]] = getFloat(arguments[i-4]);
        }
    }
    return constructor;
}
```

Here's the explanation: i've 9 value: the 5 first are ID
The 4 next are the value in the 4 last ID.
Here's an exemple of what i wanted to do :

```
var A = makeStruct("a b c d e b_value c_value d_value e_value");
var B = new A(id1, id2, id3, id4, id5);
```

So B could store the 5 ID and the value of id2 to id5 ... but it just does nothing :(

I know it's quite easy, but i'm not really good in javascript ...

Thanks !

EDIt: add some code

```
function getFloat(uneID) {
    var d = document.getElementById(uneID); 
    var r = 0;
    if (d) {//not null
        d = document.getElementById(uneID).value;
        if(d){//not undefined
            r = parseFloat(d.replace(",", "."));
            r = isNaN(r) ? 0 : r;
        }
    }
    return r;
}

function makeStruct(names) {
    var names = names.split(' ');
    var count = names.length;
    function constructor() {
        for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
            this[names[i]] = arguments[i];
        }
        for (var i = 5; i < count; i++) {
            this[names[i]] = getFloat(arguments[i-4]);
        }
    }
    return constructor;
}

var Aliment = makeStruct("qtt glu pro lip cal gluv prov lipv calv");
var dej = new Aliment('<%=frmAlim.FindControl("QTTdej1").ClientID %>',
    '<%=frmAlim.FindControl("GLUdej1").ClientID %>',
    '<%=frmAlim.FindControl("PROdej1").ClientID %>',
    '<%=frmAlim.FindControl("LIPdej1").ClientID %>',
    '<%=frmAlim.FindControl("CALdej1").ClientID %>'));
```

And i'd like to have my variable "dej" like that:

```
dej.qtt = '<%=frmAlim.FindControl("QTTdej1").ClientID %>'
dej.glu = '<%=frmAlim.FindControl("GLUdej1").ClientID %>'
dej.pro = '<%=frmAlim.FindControl("PROdej1").ClientID %>'
dej.lip = '<%=frmAlim.FindControl("LIPdej1").ClientID %>'
dej.cal = '<%=frmAlim.FindControl("CALdej1").ClientID %>'
dej.gluv = getFloat('<%=frmAlim.FindControl("GLUdej1").ClientID %>')
dej.prov = getFloat('<%=frmAlim.FindControl("PROdej1").ClientID %>')
dej.lipv = getFloat('<%=frmAlim.FindControl("LIPdej1").ClientID %>')
dej.calv = getFloat('<%=frmAlim.FindControl("CALdej1").ClientID %>')
```

My problem is that all the dej.*v are equal to 0

Comment: Why are you **not** creating a runnable example?

Comment: If you define all the referenced variables, it seems to run here: https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/es44ofkw/.  You don't say what the purpose of this code is so I have no idea what you expect it to do.

Comment: FYI, there's no need to write special code to "create a struct" in Javascript.  Just assign properties to an object.  Unclear what you're accomplish here.

Comment: Sorry, i might not be clear ... 
I'm doing an really big form in ASP.NET with lot of input, so i wanted to do most of the code automatically with a struct maker. 

There isnt any error, just all the value stay at 0 and i dont know why ... i edit the main question to add some code

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems that ASP turn Labels in Span. So obviously, in javascript, the ".value" method doesnt return the value in the span.

Use InnerHTML instead ! :)